# Trying to create an SPSS Modeler Stream to calculate minimum distance between many geographic lat-long points and Points of Interest

Tags: geolocation, spss-modeler

I have a list of hundreds of thousand of addresses with their Latitude/Longitude data.

In a second table, I have the Latitude/Longitude of hundreds of gas stations.

I need to derive a table with the lat/long of the house, the distance to THE CLOSEST gas station, and the name of the gas station.

I'm trying to create a stream for SPSS Modeler (I'm using version 18.2).

In excel was fairly simple (see example below). In sheet one are the houses with lat/long, in sheet two the gas stations data, in sheet three how I did it in excel for a limited number of points, and in sheet four the resulting table. Basically, in excel I took the lat/long of each house and calculated the distance to all the gas stations and kept the smallest one.

I'll appreciate any directions or ideas on how to generate an SPSS Modeler stream to do something similar.

You can download my excel sample here: https://github.com/schapsis/calculating-distance-question

Answer (score 0):

Please see the solution posted at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/512605/how-to-calculate-distance-between-many-geographic/